# Super_gradients import Error while making object detection on clas

Tags: object-detection, yolo

While importing this "Super_gradients" I'm getting an error I have tried with different versions using pip but still, I'm facing this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' from partially initialized module 'super_gradients.training' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/training/**init**.py)

I just want to run it for yolonas_l model to train object detection model.